# Webscraping EFL Championship Fixture List in R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I have been trying to obtain the EFL Championship fixture list in excel format but haven't been able to find anything as yet. Therefore I am attempting to webscrape the following website https://www.skysports.com/championship-fixtures.

I have previously used the following code to webscrape before

```
  url <- paste0("https://www.nrl.com/draw/nrl-premiership/2023/round-22/broncos-v-roosters/")
  
  page <- read_html(url)
  
  contentnodes <-page %>% html_nodes ("div.l-content.pre-quench") %>% 
    html_attr("q-data") %>% jsonlite::fromJSON()
```

However I am not sure what the html_nodes() and html_attr() arguments should be for the skysports website

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to check out this site: https://fixturedownload.com/sport/football

Answer (score 0):

The best scraping option is not have to scrape at all, so [using this website's preprocessed information is a good idea](https://fixturedownload.com/sport/football). However, if you really wanted it another way, you can use this:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

url <- "https://www.skysports.com/championship-fixtures"
page <- read_html(url)
divs <- html_nodes(page, ".fixres__body") %>% html_children()

out = tibble(
  date = as.Date(character()),
  home = character(),
  away = character(),
  time = character()
)
for (div in divs) {
  if (str_detect(string = html_text(div), pattern = "^\\w+ \\d+$")) {
  } else if (str_detect(string = html_text(div), pattern = "^\\w+ \\d+\\w+ \\w+$")) {
    current_date = div %>% html_text() %>% paste("2023") %>% str_remove("(?<=\\d)\\w+") %>% as.Date("%A %d %B %Y")
    print(current_date)
  } else {
    home = div %>% html_nodes(".matches__participant--side1.matches__participant.matches__item-col") %>% html_text() %>% str_trim()
    away = div %>% html_nodes(".matches__participant--side2.matches__participant.matches__item-col") %>% html_text() %>% str_trim()
    time = div %>% html_nodes(".matches__date") %>% html_text() %>% str_trim()
    out = out %>% add_row(date = current_date, home = home, away = away, time = time)
  } 
}
out <- mutate(out, time = parse_time(time))
```